# Automorphism of fundamental group of torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am asked to show that every automorphism of the fundamental group of a torus $T=S^1\times{}S^1$ is induced by a homeomorphism $h:T\rightarrow{}T$, which fixes the base point.

What I was thinking is composing rotations in $R^3$ and the antipodal map on $T$, which will give me base-point preserving homeomorphisms of $T$. These homeormorphisms will obviously induce automorphisms of the group $\pi_1(T)$.

But how do I show that *all* the automorphisms are induced this way? <strike>I can see that the order of the group $Aut(\pi_1(T))$ is $8$ and so I have to produce $8$ such homeomorphism!</strike> Is there any other elegant way?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Added:** As pointed out in the comments, I miscalculated the order of the group $Aut(\pi_1(T))$. But then my original argument is not working at all. Any help?

Comment: Does $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ really only have $8$ automorphisms?

Comment: @Nishant, I was thinking $(m,n)\rightarrow{}(m,\pm{}n)$,  $(m,n)\rightarrow{}(\pm{}m,n)$, $(m,n)\rightarrow{}(n,\pm{}m)$ and $(m,n)\rightarrow{}(\pm{}n,m)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think $(m, n)\mapsto(m, m+n)$ also works.

Comment: an automorphism of $Z^2$ corresponds to a $2\times 2$-matrix which is invertible, i.e. the determinant is $\pm 1$.

Comment: @Dan, Thanks for that! I've changed the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the torus as $\Bbb{R}^2 / \Bbb{Z}^2$.  The map
$$
\begin{align}
\Bbb{R}^2 &\overset{\normalsize\tilde{\varphi}^{}_A}{\to} \Bbb{R}^2 \\
\begin{bmatrix} s \\ t \end{bmatrix} 
&\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} as+bt \\ cs+dt \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
with $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \in GL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ satisfies $\tilde{\varphi}^{}_A(\Bbb{Z}^2) \subseteq \Bbb{Z}^2$.  Therefore, it descends to
$$
\begin{align}
T &\overset{\normalsize\varphi^{}_A}{\to} T \\
\begin{bmatrix} s \\ t \end{bmatrix} 
&\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} as+bt \pmod{1} \\ cs+dt \pmod{1} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
For any $A \in GL_2(\Bbb{Z}) \cong \operatorname{Aut}\pi_1(T)$, this is an explicit construction of a self-homeomorphism of $\varphi^{}_A$ of $T$ such that
$$
\bigl( \varphi^{}_A \bigr)_* = A.
$$

Comment: I know this is an old post, but is it necessary to say anything about the base points being preserved?